# Does the argument in main function in java 'String[] args' creates an object?

Tags: java, string, program-entry-point, args

Does the argument in java main function `String[] args` create any object in jvm?
How to understand what objects are created after execution of class?

Comment: Arrays are objects, so yes, the JVM creates a `String[]` and stores the command-line arguments in it. A remark: In Java, the array-brackets are normally written directly following the type, not in front of the variable name (`String []args` -> `String[] args`)

Comment: Many class (and `String`) instances are created when the JVM runs. **Why** do you want to know?

Comment: "How to understand what objects are created after execution of class?" - after execution? I don't see why any objects would be created after execution of a class